# Modrewrite and PHP issues

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write this rewrite code and it just is not working (apache 2.2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account/activate\?token=(.*) index.php?route=account/activate&token=$1
```

I tried many different variations. After trying for about and hour and searching google I am stumped. This is where you come in!

Comment: Maybe throw in a little explanation of what you're trying to do? Maybe a few examples of incoming URIs and outgoing, and what parameters you're hoping to preserve?

Comment: What's not working? What is the problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite working for other rules?

Comment: Yes mod rewrite is working for other rules. 
Example url: site.com/account/activate?token=thisisamd5hash
I basically want that to go to:
site.com/index.php?route=account/activate&token=md5hash

Comment: What does the Rewrite-Log say?

Comment: No idea what that is, so I couldn't tell you. If it is a server side thing, I am on a shared server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^account/activate$ index.php?route=account/activate&%1
```

Basically this maps the entire query string to %1 in the RewriteRule and you can then access your token from your php-script using good old regular $_GET['token']

Answer (score 2):

The pattern of the [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is only tested agains the URI path. The query string can only be tested with the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.*)
RewriteRule ^account/activate$ index.php?route=account/activate&token=%1
```

But there’s a simpler solution: Just set the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to get the query string automatically appended to the new query string:

```
RewriteRule ^account/activate$ index.php?route=account/activate [QSA]
```

Note: You just need to set the `QSA` flag if there is a query defined in the substitution. If not, the original query already will automatically appended.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^account/activate/?$ index.php?route=account/activate&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^account/activate/?/$ index.php?route=account/activate&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And it works with this:

```
<?php 

echo "route is: " . $_GET['route'];
echo "</br>";
echo "token is " . $_GET['token'];
```

My directory where my code resides in is called test.
These are my urls:

http://localhost:80/test/account/activate/?token=test
http://localhost:80/test/account/activate/?token=asd

Comment: Ok did you try replacing you're entire .htaccess with my snippit. If that doesn't work I think its a configuration error. Maybe you could post the whole htaccess.

Comment: It matches yours perfectly. The page comes up and the router var works but the token is empty.

Comment: I think we are on the wrong page, I want the url to display ?token= , such as /account/activate/?token=adasdasd

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match the parameters part of your URL with mod_rewrite.

The only way to test for parameter in your URL is to use a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive and testing the env variable QUERY_STRING